# Bulk operations: Taxonomy: Save

Tags: 7, views, location

I am just looking to do a bulk save on a bunch of taxonomy terms - need to trigger an update on a geofield - but there is no Save option in the bulk operations for Taxonomy Terms (as there is for Nodes).
When I try to update a field on the terms with Modify Entity Value, I get an AJAX error...
Ditto when I try to do a taxonomy_term_save($object) with Execute Arbitrary PHP Script.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Simon.

Answer (score 1):

taxonomy_term_save($entity); inside "Execute Arbitrary PHP Script" will do the trick.
In D7, the variable is $entity, for D6 it is $object.

Comment: Thanks Bojan - appreciate the tip! Unfortunately this just saves, but doesn't update the taxonomy term - any suggestion of how I can trigger update to force the geofield to generate?

Comment: I'm not familiar with geofield triggers generation, you will probably have to ask in their issue queue.

Comment: Okay - thanks Bojan - I know that they have a drush backfill command, but it only works on Nodes...

Comment: I needed to do this again in a different context and the code snippet worked fine on a computed field - must be something specific to the geofield which failed in the first instance...